# Object out of bounds on a custom list returned

Tags: c#, generic-list

The following code works for to show people who have holidays with an icon in my calendar but the problem i have is the first line of code in my for statement where i extract the date times

```
protected void apertureAppointments_TimeSlotCreated(object sender, TimeSlotCreatedEventArgs e)

        int i = 0;
        bool isFound = false;
        List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern> _list = new List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern>();
        _list = _dal.getHolidays();
        List<Resource> resources = new List<Resource>(apertureAppointments.Resources.GetResourcesByType("Managers"));
        Resource res = resources[5];

        foreach (tblApertureNetShiftPattern sp in _list)
        {
            if (_list.Count >= 1)
                i++;
            else
                i = 0;

            DateTime? dt1 = _list[i - 1].startdate;
            DateTime? dt2 = _list[i - 1].endDate;
            if (e.TimeSlot.Start == dt1 && e.TimeSlot.Resource.Text == sp.manager_name)
            {
                isFound = true;
                if (DoDateRangesOverlap(e.TimeSlot.Start, e.TimeSlot.End, dt1, dt2) && isFound == true)
                {
                    Label temperatureLabel = new Label();

                    if (sp.appointmentType == Constants.shiftDayoff)
                    {
                        e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "DayOfCssStyle";

                        temperatureLabel.CssClass = "DayOfCssStyle";
                    }
                    else if (sp.appointmentType == Constants.shiftHoliday)
                    {
                        e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "HolidayCssStyle";
                        temperatureLabel.CssClass = "HolidayCssStyle";
                    }
                    else if (sp.appointmentType == Constants.shiftStat)
                    {
                        e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "statCssStyle";
                        temperatureLabel.CssClass = "statCssStyle";
                    }
                    else if (sp.appointmentType == Constants.shiftsickDay)
                    {
                        e.TimeSlot.CssClass = "SickDayStyle";
                        temperatureLabel.CssClass = "SickDayStyle";
                    }
                    temperatureLabel.Text = sp.Description;

                    Image imageControl = new Image();

                    imageControl.ImageUrl = @"~\images\aperturenet\Calendar\resources\holidays.png";

                    temperatureLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;

                    dt1 = null;
                    dt2 = null;
                    isFound = false;
                    e.TimeSlot.Control.Controls.AddAt(1, temperatureLabel);
                    e.TimeSlot.Control.Controls.AddAt(2, imageControl);
                }
            }
        }
```

My Problem lies in this code here

> ```
>  if (_list.Count >= 1)
>                 i++;
>             else
>                 i = 0;
>             DateTime? dt1 = _list[i - 1].startdate;
>             DateTime? dt2 = _list[i - 1].endDate;
> ```

When I do not have the -1 in the [ array int] it bombs out because obv the list shows 0,1 and the loop probally shows 2 items. What is the best way to avoid the object out of range index error.?

Getholidays is just a simple list of when the staf memeber our off so nothing to fancy here.

```
 public List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern> getHolidays()
 {
        List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern> list = new List<tblApertureNetShiftPattern>();

        var q = from _holidays in apertureNetEntities.tblApertureNetShiftPatterns.Where(w => w.isDeleted == false)
                select _holidays;

        list = q.ToList();

      return list;
 }
```

Also is their a neater way of doing I somehow feel that my code is very bloated.

Comment: I'd also move the whole if/elseif thing into a dictionary and then access it directly. This contains duplicate code

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, these are the lines causing your problem? Because you can only enter the body of the `foreach` loop if the `_list` contains at least one element. Thus, `_list.Count >= 1` will always be true, and `i` will be incremented and never become `-1`.

I suspect your out of bound exception originating from this line of code

```
List<Resource> resources = new List<Resource>(apertureAppointments.Resources.GetResourcesByType("Managers"));
Resource res = resources[5];
```

Are you sure, there are always at least 6 items in this list?

Generally, why do you access your listitems by index, if you iterate them with a `foreach` loop? YOu could easily do it as follows

```
foreach (tblApertureNetShiftPattern sp in _list) {

    DateTime? dt1 = sp.startDate;
    DateTime? dt2 = sp.endDate;
}
```

just like you do it with the `manager_name` property.

If you insist on accessing by index, I suggest incrementing the index variable `i` at the end of the loop. This way you won't always have to decrement the index before accessing the array.

Comment: Yes they are always 6 managers for the time being of the program

Comment: If that is true, with your posted code there is no way, that there will be an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Well, OP said "When I do not have the -1 in the [ array int] …". Obviously removing the `-1` will lead to out of bounds. The true question, then, is why is there `i++` in the first place?

Comment: @mathiasettinger ah, you're right, must have missed that in the OP text. In my opinion, the real question is, why does OP use indexes at all? ;)